# Angular 7 - Detect when component in viewport

Tags: angular, angular7

I have an app in Angular 7 with a component that has many child components. The issue I have is due to the number of components there is a slight lag when the app is fully loaded in the view port. Therefore I am trying to show a loading wheel that disappears once all the components are fully loaded and in view.

Is there a way to check or an event to say when a component has loaded and showing in the view port?

As a test I've tried the lifecycle hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    alert('Component Loading complete');
  }
```

But unfortunately this alert shows before the components are actually in the view port.

Appreciate any guidance and light weight solutions. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on but you could give a try to the [requestAnimationFrame method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Can we see the template markup?

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is the correct life cycle hook. I think you are trying to compensate for an overly populated DOM with a loading screen. Use something like a virtualized list to reduce the number of elements rendered at a time. The only delays should be network delays and the initial bootstrap delay

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to check or an event to say when a component has loaded and showing in the viewport?

All view components are *created* when `ngAfterViewInit()` is triggered.

You can listen for *changes* to the [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) by using queries.

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e?gi=e81ee3df6cab

This query will only tell you when a DOM element *exists*, and this might not be the *context* to remove the loading wheel. The alternative is to notify the *parent* component via a *child* component. For example; after loading data from HTTP.

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
        <div class="loading" *ngIf="!(loaded$ | async)"></div>
        <child-component></child-component>
    `
})
export class Parent Component {
     public loaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
}

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
     public constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient,
                        private _parent: ParentComponent) {}

     public ngOnInit() {
         this._httpClient.get('stuff').subscribe(() => {
             this._parent.loaded$.next(true);
         });
     }
}
```

You can improve upon this approach by adding a *service* as the manager for the children. So that the children are not coupled directly to the parent. The key here is the usage of observables to emit changes about the state of children.